# Java 2 column number formatting

Tags: java, formatting

I am trying to translate a C# example of number formatting into Java.  The idea is to format the numerical output into 2 "columns" (or 2 characters) for neatness.

With C#, this is done by

```
Console.WriteLine("{0:00;-0;00}", theInt);
```

So that 25, 7, -1, 0 prints like:

```
25
07
-1
00
```

Is there any good way to do this in Java? (besides writing my own function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for.

```
 String.format("%02d", yournumber);
```

**[==> SEE HERE FOR DEMO](http://compilr.com/johntotetwoo/sampleformat/Program.java)**

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This did the trick! (sorry I apparently can't upvote as I don't have any rep yet)

Answer (score 1):

you have formatted printing in java

```
System.out.printf("%02d %02d %02d %02d",25,7,-1,0);
```

and if you put \n, it will print every number in next line.

```
System.out.printf("%02d\n%02d\n%02d\n%02d",25,7,-1,0);
```

Comment: Thank you, I had something like that, but for some reason, I wasn't sure about the negative numbers.

Comment: I executed the above line and it gave me the same output as you mentioned. but if it did not fulfill your requirement then its ok.

Comment: No, it did, and I had your answer checked as correct at first!  But then John Totet Woo provided a prettier answer, so I checked his instead.  You are both correct, and I thank you for your answer.  I apologize that I cannot upvote, as I have no rep yet.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be looking for something like [java.util.Formatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html), which provides ways to format text output, specify column widths, and intelligently format common things like floating point numbers and dates, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
String.format(...)
```

using [formatting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html)